# Change a text in child with another closing element(s)

Tags: jquery, string, text, append

**Example HTML :**

```
<div>
    <input></input>
    Change me
</div>
```

1. How can I change my text `Change me` to `Another text` ?
2. How can I append some text like `Change me` to `Change me please`

I know only I can append some text with element like..

```
var new_text = "<span>please</span>";
$(new_text).appendTo("div");
```

But how can I append without any element like `<span>`?

**Playground + Testing here :** http://jsfiddle.net/yU4Qj/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the `.contents()` of your `<div>` until you find the required text node, whose contents you can then modify by altering its `.nodeValue` property.

```
$('div').contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.match(/Change/)) {
        this.nodeValue = "I've been changed!";
    }
});
```

A better solution though would be to wrap the original text node in a `<span>` so that you can access it directly via DOM selectors.  You could perform that wrapping automatically (i.e. using JS code, not by changing the source) when the page is first loaded, and then use normal jQuery selectors and methods.

Comment: expand about .contents() vs .html() pls :D look at @Reigel's anwser look like easier

Comment: `.contents()` gives you direct access to the native DOM nodes, but unlike other jQuery methods gives you text nodes as well as elements and lets you modify those text nodes directly.  See comments on Reigel's answer about why using `.html()` is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks , and to appending I do like this http://jsfiddle.net/yU4Qj/3/ Can you look at this , it's ok ?

Answer (score 1):

there are so many ways you can do to achieve it...
one way is this...

```
var new_text = "please";
$('div').html(function(i,h){
return h + new_text;
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/yU4Qj/1/)

Comment: Nice one , so I can do `return h.replace("Change me", "New text");` to edit my text

Comment: no, this is _not_ a nice one.  It relies on serialising the existing DOM, modifying a string, and then deserialising it again.  This would destroy any event handlers or data attached to those nodes.

Comment: If I using even haldlers in .live() .on('click') ? @Alnitak

Comment: If you use `.live()` / delegate `.on()` it's OK, but IMHO `.html()` should only be used to create new nodes, not modify them.  Serialising and then deserialising HTML is almost never the proper answer.

Comment: no more `.live()` on version 1.9... yes `.on()` should work... but still you should be careful... other used plugins might not work...

Comment: @Reigel yes about .live() in nomore in 1.9, I said both (`.on()` too):P

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').contents().filter(function() {; return this.nodeType == 3; }).replaceWith('I have changed')
```